# Including a dependent assembly into a NuGet package in VS2017

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I have a solution with 2 projects (NET Core). The first project (library) contains the main assembly, the other project (library) contains an assembly with resources, interfaces and other stuff. The main project references the second project.

I am using Visual Studio 2017. When I create a NuGet package from the main project, the satellite assembly is not included in the package's lib folder. How can this be achieved?

Note: I don't want to reference the satellite assembly as NuGet package, I want this assembly to be part of the main package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:
nuget pack mainproject.csproj -IncludeReferencedProjects

Comment: Yeah, did the trick.
Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference
Quote: Indicates that the built package should include referenced projects either as dependencies or as part of the package. If a referenced project has a corresponding .nuspec file that has the same name as the project, then that referenced project is added as a dependency. Otherwise, the referenced project is added as part of the package.

Comment: How to make it work with build into visual studio nuget package manager? I was trying to add **<IncludeReferencedProjects>True</IncludeReferencedProjects>** into my .csproj file and it doesn't work.

Comment: Didn't work for me :-( Also, the link in @helgans comment no longer mentions `IncludeReferencedProjects` nor it contains the text he quoted

Comment: How can I achieve the equivalent to adding -IncludeReferencedProjects to the command line when there's no command line (e.g. when I just use the "package" project properties in VS2022, or when I'm writing a DevOps pipeline that relies on a simple out-of-the-box DevOps template) ?