# Package on build in VS 2017 does not pack referenced assemblies

Tags: .net, .net-core, nuget, .net-standard

With 'Pack' tab in .NET Core/Standard projects in VS 2017 one can easily automate packaging of a project. However, references to other projects from solution are understandably not packed. The only way to pack the dependencies using this flow is to send each one to NuGet, install it from NuGet, remove the solution dependency (reference the NuGet, not the assembly).

My question:
Having 2 .NET Standard projects A and B in a solution, where B depends on A, what is the easiest way to obtain two NuGets - A.nupkg and B.nupkg, where B.nupkg contains a reference to A.nupkg?

**EDIT**: Having both PackageReference and ProjectReference to dll with same name is a pitfall, but the VS2017 seems to only pack dlls that are added as PackageReference. I'd like to build a solution using local files, but pack the B.nupkg using PackageReference to A.nupkg.

**EDIT2** Up to this moment, I switched references from project to NuGet, build & packaged, than switched back. Now I decided it's waste of time and I'm typing PS script calling `dotnet pack` with desired targets, but maybe there is easier way, leveraging built in 'Package' tab?

Comment: This is far from ideal of course, you'll want a single package that delivers all the dependencies as well.  The VS2017 tooling is grossly inadequate to do this correctly and they don't seem to be in hurry to improve it.  IncludeReferencedProjects is the key, but it has sharp edges as well, reference question [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42998571/including-a-dependent-assembly-into-a-nuget-package-in-vs2017).

Comment: Thanks. It probably packs them as dlls, whereas I want PackageReference. It would be stupid to have Nuget Nuget B with both A.dll and B.dll istead of just a ref to A.nupkg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add new configuration like 'Pack' and than repace in *.projs all desired ProjectReferences with PackageReferences.

So first: Solution -> RMB -> ConfigurationManager -> New configuration (select from the dropdown)

[image]

It will add new build configuration to the .sln file and appropriate entries to all *.proj files.

Than in each project you'd like to build a package for, add mutually exclusive conditions like this:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Stocks.Data.Model" Version="2.0.0" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Pack'" />
    <PackageReference Remove="Stocks.Data.Model" Version="2.0.0" Condition="'$(Configuration)' != 'Pack'" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Stocks.Data.Model\Stocks.Data.Model.csproj" Condition="'$(Configuration)' != 'Pack'" />
    <ProjectReference Remove="..\Stocks.Data.Model\Stocks.Data.Model.csproj" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Pack'" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

As you can see, this is same dll, just one from NuGet and one from local solution. This way you can build all your NuGets with proper dependencies with one drop down change. It's the cleanest solution, leveraging built in mechanics. Also don't forget to enable 'Generate NuGet package on build' for it to work.

Note, that currently VS will temporarly warn with yellow warning icon about dll with same name added in Dependencies, but it's correct, since there is one dll per config - reloading the solution fixes this.

References:

- [Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files)
- [Open Source project where it's implemented](https://github.com/PFalkowski/StocksData)